# General questions on parameterized test in googletest

Tags: googletest

background:I am writing a Session table for incoming traffic. This table should hold all active UDP/TCP connections.

I am using googletest package to test my implementation.
I prepare a parameterised test based on fixture in the following format:

```
class SessionTest - initialize all staff.

struct ConnectionInfo - holds set of connection parameters (IPs, ports, etc..)

class SessionTestPrepare : SessionTest , testing::WithParamInterface<ConnectionInfo> - initialization.

TEST_P(SessionTestPrepare, test) - holds the test cases and logic.

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(default, SessionTestPrepare_ testing::Values(  
ConectionInfo{},  
ConectionInfo{},  
ConectionInfo{},
```

)

I noticed that each time new parameters are tested, the SessionTest constructor and Setup function are called (and of course destructor and TearDown).
Note: my sessionTable is declared and initialized here.

1. Is there a way to avoid calling to SetUp and TearDown after each set of parameter test?
2. Is there a way to keep the state of my Session Table after each test without make it global (i.e. when testing the second connection parameters, the first is still in table)?

Answer (score 4):

To run set up and tear down only once in a test fixture, use `SetUpTestCase` and `TearDownTestCase` instead of `SetUp` and `TearDown`. And the [shared resources](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#sharing-resources-between-tests-in-the-same-test-case) can be stored in fixture with static member variables. For example:

```
class SessionTestPrepare : public ::testing::WithParamInterface<ConnectionInfo> //...
{
public:
    static void SetUpTestCase();
    static void TearDownTestCase();

    static ConnectionInfo * shared_data;
    //...
}
```

`SetUpTestCase` is called before the first parameter test begins and `TearDownTestCase` is called after the last parameter test ends. You can create/delete the shared resources in these functions.